# If $f$ is injective and $g$ is not injective, $g\circ f$ is not injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

If $f$ is injective and $g$ is not injective, $g\circ f$ is not injective?

If $f$ is surjective and $g$ is not surjective, $g\circ f$ is not surjective?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think g o f is not injective and is not surjective.

Comment: @sdnaksn Why do you think that $g \circ f$ is not injective nor surjective?

Comment: @the_candyman because I know for sure that if f and g are both injective then g o f is injective, and if f and g are both surjective then g o f is surjective. So I was supposing that for this reason in this case g o f is not injective nor surjective

Comment: @DietrichBurde my question is about the composite function NOT BEING injective or surjective tho

Comment: Any combination has been solved here, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208756/sufficient-necessary-conditions-for-g-circ-f-being-injective-surjective-or?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde so my answer is yes or no?

Comment: If $f$ is injective, and $g$ is not, then $g\circ f$ could still be injective. So answer is no. Did you read the duplicates on the right hand side?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the 1st question: $g$ can be injective in a smaller subset.
Hint for the 2nd question: apply the definition.

Answer (score 0):

What you conjectured in the comments is correct:

1. Take $f\colon\{1\}\longrightarrow\mathbb N$ and $g\colon\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb N$ defined by $f(1)=1$ and $g(n)=1$ respectively. Then $g\circ f=f$, which is injective.
2. If $g$ is not surjective, then $g\circ f$ cannot be surjective, because if $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ is a function from $B$ to $C$, if there is a $c\in C$ which cannot be expressed as $g(b)$ for some $b\in B$, then $c$ cannot be expressed as $g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)$ for soma $a\in A$ also. Otherwise, you would just take $b=f(a)$.